# update select dropdown values using angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, dropdown

I have a drop down(dropddown2) which is displayed using a json object:

```
listData:[{id:"1",label:"lbl1"},{id:"2",label:"lbl2"}]
```

When I select a value in dropddown1, I need to add a value to the dropdown2 list and display it. I think I am able to push the data, but I cannot see it on UI.

Comment: Please add your angularJS code that is building your list to your question.

Answer (score 0):

On dropdown1, you'll need to add an event listener for the onchange event that triggers a function where you can capture the selected value and add a new value to the other dropdown.

You can do something like this:

```
<select id="carsSelector" onchange="addToSelector();">...</select>

function addToSelector() {
    var val = document.getElementById('carsSelector').value;

    var selector = document.getElementById('addSelector');
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = val;
    selector.add(option);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s35svnx/) showing this.